# How can I move all subfolders in a directory up one level, taking their contents with them?

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, scripting

I use Windows Media player to rip CDs, and it places the music in a directory structure:
My Music
--Artist 1
----Album 1
--Artist 2
----Album 2
----Album 3
Is there a way to simply take all the Album directories and move them up one level, out of their respective 'Artist' directories, so that all the albums lie in the My Music directory, like so?
My Music
--Album 1
--Album 2
--Album 3
I have been going into each folder and cut-pasting it out of the middleman directory for years, so if there's a way to automate this with a batch file that'd be fantastic.

I've tried a powershell script:

```
$category_list = Get-ChildItem *\*\*

Get-ChildItem *\*\*\* | % { Move-Item $_.FullName (($_.Parent).Parent).FullName }

$category_list | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

but all it does is delete the lowest directory down and then complain:

```
Move-Item : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "destination" is null. Change the value of argument "destination" to a non-null value.
```

I'd rather not use powershell if I can help it, since I'm not experienced with the commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get when you do `Get-ChildItem *\*\*\*` ? If you're getting files too, then that's the reason why your code is failing. To refer to the parent directory of a file you would use `.Directory` not `.Parent`.

You should do the following instead:

```bash
$folders = Get-ChildItem path\to\mymusic\*\* -Directory
$folders | Move-Item -Destination { $_.Parent.Parent.FullName }
$folders.Parent.FullName | Sort-Object -Unique | Remove-Item
```

Worth noting this will fail as soon as you have 2 or more album folders with the same name.

Comment: Thanks! This does move the folders in the way I was hoping! Before I mark the question as answered, however, how would I delete the artist folders which are now left over?

Comment: @TI89Titanium my bad, missed the part where you wanted to also delete them. See the update. Test the code with a copy of the actual folders before using it with the real ones

Comment: Looks great, thank you! You've saved me so much time!